# PostgreSQL Selecting and Grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I'm newish to SQL and playing with a Pokemon database to learn. Starting to grasp some differences with MYSQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL.

SQLlite allows me to use the following query to grab Pokemon with only a single type (they have only one row using the Select statement as type_names.name will generate two rows--one for each type--if they have two types):

```
    -- displays all pokemon of a single type (no dual-types)
SELECT pokemon_species.id,
       pokemon_species.identifier,
       type_names.name
FROM pokemon_species
    JOIN pokemon_types ON pokemon_species.id = pokemon_types.pokemon_id
    JOIN type_names ON pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id
GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY pokemon_species.id;
```

PostgreSQL, however, will give the "[42803] ERROR: column "type_names.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 70" error.

I've found the following query works with PostgreSQL:

```
-- displays all pokemon of a single type (no dual-types)
WITH species AS (
    SELECT pokemon_species.id,
           pokemon_species.identifier
    FROM pokemon_species
             JOIN pokemon_types ON pokemon_species.id = pokemon_types.pokemon_id
             JOIN type_names ON pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id
    GROUP BY 1, 2
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ORDER BY pokemon_species.id
)

SELECT species.*, type_names.name  
    FROM species
             JOIN pokemon_types ON species.id = pokemon_types.pokemon_id
             JOIN type_names ON pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id;
```

Joining the three tables twice, seems redundant and I am wondering--how could this query be written better?

Result example:

```
id | identifier | type_name
-- | ---------- | ---------
4  | charmander | Fire
5  | charmeleon | Fire
7  | squirtle   | Water
8  | wartortle  | Water
9  | blastoise  | Water
10 | caterpie   | Bug
11 | metapod    | Bug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for just one matching row in each group, so you can use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT ps.id, ps.identifier, MAX(tn.name) as name
FROM pokemon_species ps JOIN
     pokemon_types pt
     ON ps.id = pt.pokemon_id JOIN
     type_names tn
     ON pt.type_id = tn.type_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ps.id;
```

Presumably, `pokemon_species.id` is declared as a primary key.  That is why you can leave `ps.identifier` out of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Didn't think to throw in an aggregation that does nothing but satisfy the error message. I also didn't realize that ps.identifier didn't need to be part of the GROUP BY as ps.id is the primary key for that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the pokemon ids that are single type.

```
SELECT pokemon_species.id,
       pokemon_species.identifier,
       type_names.name
FROM pokemon_species
    JOIN pokemon_types ON pokemon_species.id = pokemon_types.pokemon_id
    JOIN type_names ON pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id
WHERE pokemon_species.id IN (
   SELECT pokemon_id
   FROM pokemon_types
   GROUP BY pokemon_id 
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Or you could use window functions to count the different types, and then filter

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT pokemon_species.id,
       pokemon_species.identifier,
       type_names.name as type_name,
       COUNT(distinct type_names.name) OVER (PARTITION BY pokemon_species.id) as type_count
FROM pokemon_species
    JOIN pokemon_types ON pokemon_species.id = pokemon_types.pokemon_id
    JOIN type_names ON pokemon_types.type_id = type_names.type_id
)
SELECT id,
       identifier,
       type_name
FROM CTE
WHERE type_count=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I wanted to mention that the first option is a working solution and that I completely forgot about 'IN'.

I read a bit about window functions in looking for a solution to this, but haven't really tried any yet. This one though throws a "[0A000] ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions" error.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Join after the aggregation:

```
SELECT ps.id,
       ps.identifier,
       tn.name
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         identifier,
  FROM pokemon_species 
  GROUP BY ps.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) ps 
  JOIN pokemon_types pt ON ps.id = pt.pokemon_id
  JOIN type_names tn ON pt.type_id = tn.type_id
ORDER BY pokemon_species.id;
```